# How to add a "created at" column in a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a form on my website and when somebody fill it the info are copied in my database.

The table is named "form" and its 5 columns:

- id
- email
- phone number
- country
- platform

I now need to know when each form entry was submitted, and would like to add a "created at" column which will be filled with the creation time/date timestamp.

Can I retrieve the created date for the row already saved in the table?

Comment: Find the answer:
    ALTER TABLE `form`
    ADD COLUMN `created`
    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 

Have a nice day,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run this script in phpMyAdmin?

```
ALTER  TABLE Form 
   ADD Column CreatedOn timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ;
```